# Device detection in grails version 2

Tags: grails-2.0

We're building a multi platform application in grails 2. I'm aware we can use JQuery mobile to build the views, but what's the best plugin for device detection in grails 2.

The Spring plugin is for Grails version : 1.3.6  , is there some work around for this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use http://grails.org/plugin/browser-detection - it's actively maintained (updated last month)

Comment: Thanks Burt.But http://grails.org/plugin/browser-detection is targeted at Grails 1. I'm learning Grails now, so maybe I'm missing something , but I didn't think Grails 2 was backwards compatible. I get unending errors in STS when I try to combine Grails 1 and 2 plug-ins.

Comment: It says it supports 1.2.2 or higher, so it should work with 2.0. This isn't always the case, but I doubt this plugin does anything that wouldn't be compatible. Did you try this plugin and get errors?

Comment: Sorry it was a newbie error, not one with the plug-in. Thanks it's just what I'm looking for. It's simple to use as well , which is probably a good thing!

Answer (score 0):

Use grails spring mobile plugin. Find here how to implement device detection using spring mobile plugin. http://jagadeeshmanne.blogspot.in/2014/02/grails-mobile-device-detection-using.html